# get an array of "val" attributes values from the rows of a table

Tags: jquery

```
<table id ='t1'>
<tr val='1'></tr>
<tr val='2'></tr>
<tr val='3'></tr>
<tr val='4'></tr>
<table>
```

how to get from this an array = 1,2,3,4

Comment: `val` is not a valid attribute for `tr`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
var arr = $("#t1 tr").map(function() { return $(this).attr("val"); }).get();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7hb2e/).

Comment: This, for me, is an example of a perfect answer. It's explanatory, succinct, beautiful code, with a link to documentation and a test harness. Not many people make time to create answers like this - me included (!) - this this is really stellar. Nice work Nick.

Comment: @ndtreviv - thanks :) I try to remember that you're not answering the question, but future googlers as well, documentation link is mandatory IMO!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$.map( $( "table#t1 tr"), function( item) { return $(item).attr("val");})
```